# How to change the color of the background in a Networkx plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to change the background color of a networkx generated graph using matplotlib. But it seems my code only changes the external background, not the background of the graph itself. Example code:

```
import psutil
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mlist = psutil.net_connections(kind="all")
Node = nx.Graph()

Node.add_node("localhost")

for v, val in enumerate(mlist):
    if val[4] != () and val[4][0] != "127.0.0.1":
        print(str(val[4][0]) + " - " + str(val[6]))
        print(psutil.Process(val[6]).name())
        Node.add_node(str(val[4][0]))
        Node.add_edge(str(val[4][0]), "localhost")

fig = plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(Node, pos=nx.spring_layout(Node, 25), bg_color=[1,1,1,1], alpha=0.1, with_labels=False, node_size=100, node_color="green")
fig.set_facecolor("blue")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the background color with `ax.set_facecolor`. 
If you don't created an `ax`, you could use `plt.gca().set_facecolor`. 
If you also want to remove the black border, use `ax.axis('off')`.
Note that the `bg_color=` is ignored in `nx.draw_networkx`.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx(nx.dodecahedral_graph(),
                 with_labels=False, node_shape='*', node_size=300, node_color='gold',
                 edge_color='crimson', width=5)
ax.set_facecolor('deepskyblue')
ax.axis('off')
fig.set_facecolor('deepskyblue')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
nx.draw_networkx(Node, pos=nx.spring_layout(Node, 25), bg_color=[1,1,1,1], alpha=0.1, with_labels=False, node_size=100, node_color="green")
ax.set_facecolor("blue")

plt.show()
```